# Why can't this jpg resource in be found within its own library?

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

Doing some refactoring of some projects and I'm running into a resource issue that has me stumped.  I'm having trouble loading resources from within a library.  The same code runs fine within the main app (if I move the resource there of course.)

Here's the app version that works...

```
MyApp.csproj
 - Resources
    - Images
       SomeFile.jpg <-- Set to 'Resource' in the properties grid
```

I then have the following code running in the app which works fine.

```cs
var imageSourceConverter = new ImageSourceConverter();
var packUriString = $"pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/SomeFile.jpg";
someImage.Source = imageSourceConverter.ConvertFromString(packUriString) as ImageSource;
```

I then try to move both this code and the resource to a new library 'MyLibrary', like so...

```
MyLibrary.csproj
 - Resources
    - Images
       SomeFile.jpg <-- Set to 'Resource' in the properties grid
```

And try the same (again, from within 'MyLibrary')...

```cs
var imageSourceConverter = new ImageSourceConverter();
var packUriString = $"pack://application:,,,/Resources/Images/SomeFile.jpg";
someImage.Source = imageSourceConverter.ConvertFromString(packUriString) as ImageSource;
```

But I now get the following...

```
System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=Cannot locate resource 'resources/images/somefile.jpg'.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  StackTrace:
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
```

I remember issues with resources in the past not being compiled so I did a 'rebuild all' to see if that helped, but it didn't.  Still get the same issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you set 'Embedded resource' in the properties Build Action?

Comment: @PaulSinnema That would be wrong. The question is about an *assembly resource file*, which needs the Build Action *Resource*.

Comment: I’m wondering if there’s different rules for loading it from within a library vs from within an app.

Comment: No, it is 100% within the library. It’s a local function in a control that was moved to the library. It’s part of that control’s initialization.

Comment: BOOM! That was it!!  Didn't think you had to specify the library from *within* that library!  Wanna move that to an answer and I'll accept it (and delete this comment?)

Comment: @Clemens, not sure if you closed this (I'm guessing so since you answered the other one) but I wouldn't.  The other one's name isn't indicative of what the problem is, and like me, people looking for answers may not be able to find it.  In contrast, this one has the exact title and description explaining the problem.  Just a suggestion because they can get there from here, but personally, I hate having to follow chains of comments and answers, reading through seemingly unrelated things, trying to find what I'm after.  (If anything, I'd suggest editing the title of the other one as a minimum.)

Comment: Changed the original question title to make it more specific.